# Python library module implementation

Tags: python

I am trying to write - and understand - some python code , and I have been struggling to realize how python libraries are imported. Let me describe my situation.

I am trying to mock a raspberry-pi-only python library (RPi.GPIO) in order to run some unittests in my (x86) laptop. In order to accomplish that, I thought I should just define the same functions, variables as the GPIO class, and have all the functions emtpy (just pass). So I had a look at the RPi.GPIO module.

Although I thought I would find the actual implementation of the GPIO class methods there, I actually saw that their body was empty. For example:

```
def add_event_detect(*args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
    """
    Enable edge detection events for a particular GPIO channel.
    channel      - either board pin number or BCM number depending on which mode is set.
    edge         - RISING, FALLING or BOTH
    [callback]   - A callback function for the event (optional)
    [bouncetime] - Switch bounce timeout in ms for callback
    """
    pass
```

So the question is, where is the actual implementation of this functions and what is the point of this empty body?  (just the pass keyword and the documentation) How and by whom is this method overriden and gets the desired functionality?

Comment: Python has a `__import__` method, which is what is called when you `import something`. You would likely have to override that to get the event. Here's the relevant docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__

Comment: Maybe this is the source: http://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/code/ci/default/tree/source/py_gpio.c#l676. There is the possibility to write C libs to Python, if you are familiar with Java, it looks similar to JNI development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual implementation of `add_event_detect` is in native C code, which you can find in your local virtualenv folder (or, as @Jean Jung indicates in the comments, [this online implementation](http://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/code/ci/default/tree/source/py_gpio.c) of RPi.GPIO.

Python modules can be written entirely in Python, but extensions are often written in C as described in [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html).

That stub implementation you see (whose implementation is just `pass`) is generated based on the native implementation. I suspect you are using PyCharm, which generates these automatically.

Comment: Yeap I am using PyCharm. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

It should be a wrapper for a C function.
And if you want to override `__import__` as Zizouz212 mentioned, use import hooks instead.

Here is a PEP describing import hooks:
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/